# Sending information via ajax partially working/failing

Tags: mysql, ajax

I am trying to send information about the user browser to a mysql database via ajax and this method that used to work perfectly on another site is now working partially, meaning that the data about the screen and browser width/ height, the color and pixel depth don't appear in my database and the information collected via php are sent/ saved.

Here is what I have in my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax_post() {
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    var url = "st.php";
    var sw = screen.width;
    var sh = screen.height;
    var bw = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var bh = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var cd = screen.colorDepth;
    var pd = screen.pixelDepth;
    var vars = "sw="+sw+"&sh="+sh+"&bw="+bw+"&bh="+bh+"&cd="+cd+"&pd="+pd;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
};
ajax_post();
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
My content here
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the content of the st.php file used to collect information via php and to send/ seve it to the database:

```
<?php

$dnt = date(DATE_COOKIE);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$rh = gethostbyaddr($ip);
$re = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$al = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];

$sw = $_POST['sw'];
$sh = $_POST['sh'];
$bw = $_POST['bw'];
$bh = $_POST['bh'];
$cd = $_POST['cd'];
$pd = $_POST['pd'];

$db_host = ********; // the host
$db_user = ********; // the user
$db_password = ***********; // the password

$connection = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(*******) or die(mysql_error());

$query = "INSERT INTO *********(dnt, ip, rh, re, ua, al, sw, sh, bw, bh, cd, pd)
VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape($dnt)."','".mysql_real_escape($ip)."','".mysql_real_escape($rh)."','".mysql_real_escape($re)."','".mysql_real_escape($ua)."','".mysql_real_escape($al)."','".mysql_real_escape($sw)."','".mysql_real_escape($sh)."','".mysql_real_escape($bw)."','".mysql_real_escape($bh)."','".mysql_real_escape($cd)."','".mysql_real_escape($pd)."')";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

I checked that I wasn't blocking any script (deactivated noscript), I tried it on Firefox and Chrome and Epiphany without any success: no data about the screen and browser width/ height, the color and pixel depth.

I don't have any idea why this is not working as I used exactly the same code one week ago on a website on the same host and it worked perfectly.

Thank you for your help.

----- EDIT -----

Thanks to @PiTheNumber I checked the Firebug Console and tracked the origin of the problem

Problem solved

Waiting 6 more hours to be able to answer my own question since I have less than 100 points of reputation and therefore cannot answer it right now.

Comment: Is anything stored at all? What does Firebug tell you about the ajax query? Did it run? What is the result? Is the st.php executed at all?

Comment: is there anything that calls the `ajax_post()` function?

Answer (score 1):

This is very nice for [mysql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Use `mysql_real_escape()` with your insert:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO *********(dnt, ip, rh, re, ua, al, sw, sh, bw, bh, cd, pd)
VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape($dnt)."'...)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PiTheNumber I checked the Firebug Console and tracked the problem to the rewriting/ redirecting of .php files that were breaking part of the POSTing of the the screen and browser width/ height, the color and pixel depth.